# jquery scrollbar not loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, scroll, scrollbar

i'm working on this link : http://nyam.eclecticshots.org .

every pages are loaded via ajax / jquery / php.

here is my question( without all problems due to different css understanding by each browser )
i'm using the script mCustomScrollBar i plly on some div (like forms or text)
i load th script @ first (in index.php) then after, when i dynamically load other pages, i have to click many times on the link to load the srcollbar. some others script are working without any problem, but this script refuse to work!!!
can you help me please !!!

how to access the problem :
creative & design (text)
laptopBags W Swag then customize (the form)
merci par avance
(The number of clicks to make scrollbar appear depends on browser (IE 4 click, Firefox 3 click, ...)

thx in advance

Comment: so, after some tries , i am here :
i've try to make a "complete" function for the ajax page  loader, and now it works perfectly with firefox... but IE, Safari, ... do not wanted to load the scrollbar anymore !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question is not anymore ...
i found a solution by using **enscroll** (see on github) wich is functionning perfectly !!!
i got my next scrollbar script for futu websites ;)
thx to those who was reading me